# What is this notification bar called and how can I add it into my app?

Tags: java, android

What is the ***exact*** name of this notification bar that pops up when any action is done, and how can I add this to my application?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [Snackbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html), one component of the [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html). It has an API very similar to a [Toast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html):

```
Snackbar
  .make(parentLayout, R.string.snackbar_text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
  .setAction(R.string.snackbar_action, myOnClickListener)
  .show(); // Don’t forget to show!
```

Note that the `parentLayout` should be a [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) if you want to be able to swipe to dismiss the Snackbar.